# AWK: Passing two arguments and weird error

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have made an awk implementation of `grep -c ^str file` and I want to pass the `file` and `str` arguments from a shell script. I am using `awk -v` twice to pass the arguments but I get a `awk: cannot open var1 (No such file or directory)` error.
I just can't get around it, I've been trying for almost an hour.
My code:

```
read -p "Give me a file name " file
read -p "Give me a string " str
awk -v var1="$file" -v var2="$str" 'BEGIN{print var1; print var2}{/^var2/}' var1 | 
awk '{if ($0 != "/s") {count++}} END {print count}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
awk -v var1="$file" -v var2="$str" 'BEGIN{print var1; print var2}{/^var2/}' $file
```

`awk` vars can only be acceded inside `awk` code (delimited by single quotes in this case) not at *shell* level where `var1` means nothing.

Note that `var2` value will be just a literal string between *slashes* `/^var2/`, use `$0 ~ "^"var` instead to access `var2` value.

In fact, your `awk` code can be rewritten as:

```
awk -v var="$str" '$0 ~ "^"var && $0 != "/s"{count++}END{print count}' $file
```

Comment: Thank you! Then there's no point in doing `-v var1="$file"` right?

Comment: Absolutely not :P @Dinos_12345

Comment: That's way better, thank you! My previous code printed nothing, even if the file had a record starting with str. It's weird because it works when I pass the variables explicitly.

Comment: The reason is simple var2 value a literal string between the slashes `/^var2/` , thats why I used `$0 ~ "^"var` instead.